# Grant from schema A of Schema B tables to schema C

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I have an application schema **U32_C5** and another schema **MIG_SRC** which has some tables and then we have a ROLE **RO_ROLE** on which we have some grants of tables from Schema **U32_C5**.
The **RO_ROLE** is assigned to another Schema **MRGO_RO** which is Read Only.

Here I need to grant select on tables from **MIG_SRC** to **MRGO_RO**  catch here is that the process which and from where I can include these grants is run from application schema **U32_C5** in production so when I tried to to something like below it says table or view does not exists (which seems to be obvious)

execute Grant from **U32_C5**

> grant select on MIG_SRC.MOBILE_CELLPHONE_PAIRINGS to MRGO_RO;

Another way which I think of is creating DB link on MRGO_RO for MIG_SRC Schema but it enables read/write operation as well on MIG_SRC tables which is not allowed on production.

DB Links is present on U32_C5 Schema for MIG_SRC Schema

So looking for a way to accomplish above task without creating DB Link any suggestion is welcome.

Sample Script of requirement what I want to achieve Please Remember I cannot and do not want Login to MIG_SRC and only way I am looking for is to do it by using U32_C5 and without DBA HELP

```
A RO ROLE Created by DBA's 

Create role RO_ROLE;

/* Create application schema, table inside it and grant select on it to RO_ROLE*/

CREATE USER U32_C5 IDENTIFIED BY U32_C5 DEFAULT TABLESPACE; 

GRANT ALTER SESSION TO U32_C5; 
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO U32_C5; 

GRANT CREATE database link TO U32_C5; 

GRANT CREATE table TO U32_C5; 


create table U32_C5_test_tab (id number);

grant select on U32_c5.U32_C5_Test_tab to RO_ROLE;


/* Create Read Only schema, grant RO_ROLE to it */

CREATE USER mrgo_ro IDENTIFIED BY mrgo_ro DEFAULT TABLESPACE;  

GRANT ALTER SESSION TO mrgo_ro; 
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO mrgo_ro; 

grant ro_role to mrgo_ro;

/* Create SRC schema, table inside it */

CREATE USER MIG_SRC IDENTIFIED BY MIG_SRC DEFAULT TABLESPACE; 

GRANT ALTER SESSION TO MIG_SRC; 
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO MIG_SRC; 

GRANT CREATE database link TO MIG_SRC; 

GRANT CREATE table TO MIG_SRC; 

create table mig_src_test_tab (id number);


/* login to Apllication Schema U32_C5 */

sqlplus U32_C5/U32_C5@SID

grant select on mig_src.mig_src_test_tab to mrgo_ro;  -- for me it gives error here at this step table or does not exist 

/* login to Read Only Schema mrgo_ro */

sqlplus mrgo_ro/mrgo_ro@SID

select * from mig_src.mig_src_test_tab;
or 
select * from mig_src_test_tab;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then `WITH GRANT OPTION` is what you're missing.

Once *someone* (A) grants privileges on their own objects to *someone else* (B), and that (B) has to "forward" those privileges to (C), then it is the `WITH GRANT OPTION` that helps.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm) says:

> Specify WITH GRANT OPTION to enable the grantee to grant the object privileges to other users and roles.

> Restriction on Granting WITH GRANT OPTION You can specify WITH GRANT OPTION only when granting to a user or to PUBLIC, **not when granting to a role**.

It means that you should grant privileges directly, not via role. That fact doesn't have to be a drawback because of named PL/SQL procedures, where privileges acquired via roles won't work anyway, so you might end up in direct grants anyway.

---

Other option - which you might consider - is related to what you said:

> when I tried to to something like below it says **table or view does not exists**

If you created a **synonym** for those tables, then you wouldn't get such an error.

---

Database link isn't an option, as you said - by using it, you have *full access* (as you have to know username/password to create the DB link, and that isn't really *read only* access).

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will sure trying explore WITH GRANT OPTION and If I am not wrong to after creating synonyms on MIG_SRC I also have to give Grants from MIG_SRC schema itself to other schemas which is another thing I am avoiding to use MIG_SRC schema.

Comment: I have edited the question and removed the plsql block which I think is not required at this time and added a sample script to re-create the scenario which I am trying to do.